# What is the function of shortcut "Alt + PrtSc + b"?

Tags: shortcuts

I find a shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> which can let my ubuntu reboot,  but what is the really function of the shortcut?

Comment: where did you see Alt+PrtSc+b? what is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: I find the shortcut accidentally, and the shortcut exists in almost every version, includes 14.04, 16.04, 18.04.

Comment: yes, you are rite, i tried it in my Ubuntu 18.04.. its rebooting easily.. may be this shortcut is very very useful for those who have multiple OS'es